# Write out the multiplication table for the following set of matrices over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Question:

Write out the multiplication table for the following set of matrices over $\mathbb Q$:

$$A=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
    1 & 0  \\
    0 & 1
  \end{array}\right)$$
 $$B=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
    -1 & 0  \\
     0 & 1 
  \end{array}\right)$$ 
 $$C=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
    1 &  0  \\
    0 & -1 
  \end{array}\right)$$ 
 $$D=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
    -1 & 0  \\
     0 & -1 
  \end{array}\right)$$

My Attempt: I am not sure what the question is asking. Is it just asking to do a 4x4 multiplication table and multiply each of the matrix by each other? For example:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& A& B & C & D \\ \hline
 A& & &\\ \hline
 B&  & &\\ \hline
 C&  & &\\ \hline
D&  & &\\ \hline
\end{array}

If that is what it's asking, should I multiply row x column or column x row?

Comment: Seems like you have to compute $16$ matrices multiplications: $A^2$, $AB$, $AC$, $AD$, $BA$, $B^2$ et cetera.

Comment: I'd be inclined to put AC in the third entry of the first row, i.e., use the "row times column" rule (and then explain that this is what you did). Either choice is OK if you explain.

Comment: At first glance, the multiplication looks commutative anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide some more context? Without further context, your guess seems reasonable. 
In this special case, the matrices are commutative, i.e. AB = BA (this is easy to see:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ll}
    a & 0  \\
    0 & b
  \end{array}\right)
  \times 
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
    c & 0  \\
    0 & d
  \end{array}\right)
=
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
    ac & 0  \\
    0 & bd
  \end{array}\right)
= 
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
    ca & 0  \\
    0 & db
  \end{array}\right)
= 
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
    c & 0  \\
    0 & d
  \end{array}\right)
\times 
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
    a & 0  \\
    0 & b
  \end{array}\right)
$$)

Therefore, you only have to compute half of that table.

simply using that $Q\backslash\{0\}$ is a commutative group with 1.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

note that $A$ is the identity matrix, and:
 $$D=-A \qquad C=-B \qquad B^2=C^2=A \qquad BC=CB=-A=D $$

so it is simple to complete the multiplication table.